# resource for getting good pre-generated characters for icewind dale

Tags: cheats, icewind-dale

Does anybody know either a cheat so I can get good pre-generated characters for icewind dale? They may be at level 1 but need the characters to have the totals of their personality traits (i.e. strength,constitution,charisma etc.) in the 90s so my game starts on a strongish note. I did check web but wasn't any wiser. Cheats such as http://www.gamespot.com/icewind-dale/cheats/ tell everything except what I want at the starting gate.

Basic question :-

I have to roll and re-roll the character to get it high which is boring while doing character creation. If there is a way to get good character stats (as in cheat) that would be the best.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Rather than ask for a resource, ask us for what you're looking for.  That will work much better, as asking for sites is a recommendation, and often get closed.

Comment: @Frank modified the question, hope this clears any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Do the characters really have to be pre-generated? You can easily start a new game and immediately quit, then edit the saves.

http://www.sorcerers.net/Games/IWD/index_editors.php

I've played quite a bit of IWD, but I haven't cheated on it before. You might be able to start a new game, create a character, then quit once the game starts and edit your **character file** (not the save data for the campaign), then start a new game and import the edited character. Can't remember off the top of my head if you can import on a new singleplayer game.

Answer (score 0):

It's an oldie but I confirm one can import a character in the singleplayer -- I just did.
Using IWD Enhanced Edition.

It's my first time playing the game and I had trouble with the party getting wiped quite early in the game so I restarted it and wanted to keep my main character.  Thus I exported it and could import it in the new game.

**Immersion hint**: Even though one can change the formation, for some scripted NPCs the party *boss* is the first character in the list when the game was created.  If you want a certain character to be referenced to in some of scenes where the NPC starts the conversation, put it at the top left of the character screen when creating the party before starting the adventure.